# Calculus II: Radius of Convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I have this math problem that states:

> In each part, write out the first four terms of the series, and then find the radius of convergence.
>   $$(a) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdot\cdot\cdot k}{1\cdot 6\cdot 11\cdot\cdot\cdot (5k-4)}}x^k$$
>   $$(b) \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^k\frac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot\cdot\cdot k}{1\cdot 8\cdot 15\cdot\cdot\cdot (7k-6)}}x^{2k+1}$$

For $(a)$ I took the $a_n$ (which was $\frac{k}{(5k-4)}$) as plugged in 1-4 and got $1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{3}{11}+\frac{1}{4}$.

I then took $\lim_{k->\infty}{\frac{k}{(5k-4)}}$ and got $L=\frac{1}{5}->R=5$

---

for (b) I took the $a_n$ (which was $\frac{k}{(7k-6)}$) as plugged in 1-4 and got $1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{11}$.

I then took $\lim_{k->\infty}{\frac{k}{(7k-6)}}$ and got $L=\frac{1}{7}->R=7$

---

I'm not sure what I did wrong. Thanks.

Comment: A single bullet is the product and three consecutive bullets are cdots, yes? (Only for editing purposes)

Comment: @ajotatxe, I added the original problem (picture)

Comment: I don't see what is wrong. Indeed $R=lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{a_{k-1}}{a_{k}}=lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{(k-1)!(5k-4)\cdot (5k-5-4)\cdots 1}{k!(5k-5-4)\cdots 1}=lim_{k\to \infty}\frac{5k-4}{k}=5$.

Comment: @TKM, what about for b?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that $a_k$ refers to the $k$:th term. That is, in (b),
$$a_k = (-1)^k\frac{1\cdots k}{1\cdot 8 \cdots (7k-6)} x^{2k+1}.$$
So, we find that
$$\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right| = \frac{k+1}{7k+1}|x|^2 \to \frac{|x|^2}{7}.$$
Here, the right hand side is less than $1$ if and only if $|x| < \sqrt{7}$.

Comment: +1 but what happens when $x = \pm \sqrt 7$?

Comment: For $x = \sqrt{7}$ the series is alternating and $|a_k| \to 0$, so it converges. For $x = -\sqrt{7}$ the series is positive, and hence diverges.

Comment: for $x=\sqrt 7$ you should also show that the sequence $|a_k|$ is decreasing. For $x=-\sqrt 7$ I agree that the series is positive, but how do you conclude that it diverges?

Comment: Since $|a_{k+1}| = \frac{k+1}{7k+1}|a_k|$, it is decreasing. If $|x| = \sqrt{7}$, then the terms does not decrease to $0$ as $k\to \infty$, hence the series is not absolutely convergent.

Comment: Ok, so would $\sum_{k=1}^{4}{a_n}=1+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}+\frac{2}{11}$?

Comment: In (a), the first four terms are $x + x^2/3 + x^3 /11 + x^4/44$.

Comment: @Raclette, so do I just ignore the $k$ in the numerator?

Comment: What? The first four terms are for $k = 1, 2, 3, 4$. E.g., for $k = 3$ in (a) you get $a_3 = \frac{1\cdot 2 \cdot 3}{1 \cdot 6 \cdot 11} x^3 = \frac{x^3}{11}$.

Comment: But notice that the first four terms has nothing to do with the radius of convergence.